Flutter AWS Amplify gen2 get data sorted from server
I am developing an android app with flutter and use AWS Amplify gen 2.
I already have the correct code so that I get the posts from the server but they are always unsorted. I need them to be sorted by creation date but am not able to find anything in the documentation and the things chatgpt give me are not understandable (implementable).
How do i get the data sorted directly from the server?
My code currently looks like this but how do i get any sorting in there. please help me i am stuck for quite some time.
  Future<List<PostData?>> getListPosts({int limit = 40}) async{
    
    try {
      final request = ModelQueries.list<PostData>(
        PostData.classType,
        where: PostData.ISACCEPTED.eq(false).and(PostData.AUTOCHECKDONE.eq(true)),
        limit: limit,
        
      );

      final response = await Amplify.API.query(request: request,).response;
      if (response.data!.items.isEmpty) {
        safePrint('errors: ${response.errors}');
        return List<PostData?>.empty(growable: true);
      }

      return response.data!.items;
    } on ApiException catch (e) {
      safePrint('Query failed: $e');
      return List<PostData?>.empty(growable: true);
    }
  }

my amplify/data/resource.ts has the following model for this data:
PostData: a.model({
    Title: a.string().required(),
    Text: a.string().required(),
    Tags: a.string().required(),
    PostID: a.string().required(), //combination of title, community name, and text at init
    CommunityName: a.string().required(),
    Creator: a.string().required(),
    RemoveCounter: a.integer().required(),
    IsAccepted: a.boolean().required(),
    TimeStamp: a.string(),
    AcceptedBy: a.string(),
    ModComment: a.string(),
    AutocheckDone: a.boolean().required(),
    NrComments: a.integer().required(),
  })
  .authorization(allow => [allow.authenticated(),])
  .identifier(['PostID']),

I thought there should be an easy way to get sorted results because it is such a basic thing.
Please I am thankfull for all the help I can get
